Unable to access our dev.azure.com/mountainside site for GIT
I/we signed up for a free account at dev.azure.com many years ago; we only use it as a GIT repository and never had trouble accessing it until near the end of 2022. At that time, our email provider switched us to Office 365 which created an Entra account for our organization. I don't know if this is related, but to confound the problem I also purchased a new Surface Pro in August of '22 and, while setting it up, created yet another account with my same work email address: lhampton@mountainside.onmicrosoft.com.
When I sign in to my/our Entra account, I see myself listed twice:

with a principal name of admin@netorg11995475.onmicrosoft.com. This has an identities of NETORG... as given in the principal name.
with a principal name of lhampton@mountainsidesoftware.com and an identities entry that is the same as the one for #1 above.

Now I'm stuck and can't login to dev.azure.com/mountainside as, every time I try, it tells me I don't have access. I've been all over the web/world trying to get this resolved but keep getting redirected. I'm guessing that my dev.azure.com identity is simply my email address, but its only a guess. What do I need to do to regain access?
Thank you,
Leonard
I opened an incident with developer community. They took me through the local account investigation process and saw that, yes, I have two accounts: 1 work and 1 personal.  I was informed that since these were ENTRA accounts I should try to get ENTRA support so posted my question here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1741672/unable-to-access-our-dev-azure-com-mountainside-si
which pointed me here.  I'm sure it is an azure issue but can't figure out how (if possible) to get free support to get it corrected.
